# changing given text to list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following text in a given file:

```
1234,A,7.99,10.3,12.8,101,0.11843,0.27276,0.30101  
87635,B,19.69,21.25,130,1203,0.1096,0.1599,0.1974
```

First, I want to get rid of the `1234` and `87635` in the front, and I also want to change `A` into the integer `"1"` and `B` into the integer `"0"`.

This is my code:

```
def convert(file):
    data = open(file, 'r')
    list1 = []
    for line in data:
        line_data = line.strip().split(',')
        if line_data[0] == "B":
            line_data[0] = 0
        else:
            line_data[0] = 1
        for i in range(len(line)):
             datalist.append(line)
    list1 = np.array(list1), float
    data.close()
    return list1
```

This is the output I want:

```
[[1234,A,7.99,10.3,12.8,101,0.11843,0.27276,0.30101], [87635,B,19.69,21.25,130,1203,0.1096,0.1599,0.1974]]
```

The output I'm currently getting is a `list` of strings, instead of the list of lists.

Comment: The output you want seems to be wrong. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Your code would not return a list of strings, unless I am very much mistaken. Are you sure this exact code gives you that output? Also, the desired output you describe is not the desired output you show at the bottom. Please try to make the question consistent :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `list` of `strings` , because you are appending to the list as -

```
datalist.append(line)
```

This appends the original `line` , not the changed `line_data` . Also, all the elements in `line_data` would still be strings (expect for the first element) , as you are never converting them to int.

This easiest here would be to use `csv` module , parse the file as csv and then pop the first element from each row that is returned and then change the second element (now first element after removing , as you want). Example -

```
def convert(file):
    import csv
    lst = []
    with open('<filename>','r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                row.pop(0)
                if row[0] == 'B':
                        row[0] = 0
                else:
                        row[0] = 1
                lst.append(list(map(float, row)))
    return lst
```

---

Example/Demo -

My a.csv -

```
1234,A,7.99,10.3,12.8,101,0.11843,0.27276,0.30101  
87635,B,19.69,21.25,130,1203,0.1096,0.1599,0.1974
```

Code and Result -

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('a.csv','r') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     lst = []
...     for row in reader:
...             row.pop(0)
...             if row[0] == 'B':
...                     row[0] = 0
...             else:
...                     row[0] = 1
...             lst.append(list(map(float, row)))
...
'1234'
'87635'
>>> lst
[[1.0, 7.99, 10.3, 12.8, 101.0, 0.11843, 0.27276, 0.30101], [0.0, 19.69, 21.25, 130.0, 1203.0, 0.1096, 0.1599, 0.1974]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without csv?